# Adding custom sales order attribute to order grid

Tags: sales-order, order-grid

I have created a custom sales order attribute using the installer of my custom mage module like this:

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
try
{
    $installer->addAttribute('order', 'sales_rep', array
    (
        'type'            => 'varchar',
        'backend_type'    => 'varchar',
        'frontend_input'  => 'varchar',
        'is_user_defined' => true,
        'label'           => 'Sales Rep',
        'visible'         => true,
        'required'        => false,
        'user_defined'    => false,
        'searchable'      => false,
        'filterable'      => false,
        'comparable'      => false,
        'default'         => ''
    ));
}
catch (Exception $ex) { }
$installer->endSetup();
```

This attribute value is normally set when orders are created programatically.

Now, I would like to show this attribute on the sales order grid, so I have duplicated this file:

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

To

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

and amended the `_prepareCollection()` method like this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array
    (
        'order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
        'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
        array('sales_rep' => 'sales_rep')
    );
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

I've verified this is generating the correct SQL by doing this:

> exit($collection->getSelect());

and it outputs:

> SELECT `main_table`.*, `order`.`sales_rep` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
>   LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id

I've also verified that this returns result by executing the above query in phpMyAdmin and I get the following:

[image]

Having done all the test, I proceeded to update the `_prepareColumns()` method on `Grid.php` by adding the following (just before `status`):

```
$this->addColumn('sales_rep', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Rep'),
    'index' => 'sales_rep',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'width' => '70px'
));
```

Now, when I refresh the sales order grid in magento backend, I am not getting any values back, it looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is possible to workout, the manually change added attribute values like if order placed I need manually change the attribute value in sales order grid, first of all how can I creat attribute and how can I Integrate to sales order table,, Is possible?

Comment: Is your Issue Solved?

Comment: yes, see below accepted answer.

Comment: could you please help @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error in column code use below code.

```
$this->addColumn('sales_rep', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Sales Rep'),
    'index' => 'sales_rep',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'width' => '70px'
));
```

you have used 'type'  => 'options' and not define options there

Comment: Ah man, all that effort and one silly typo ruins it. Thanks, spot on.

Comment: If it is solution you can mark as accepted

Comment: It shows me this error, ' Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order.sales_executive' in 'field list' '. Any help? @PrashantValanda

Comment: Have you left join attribute in collection as in question

Comment: I did the above thing. @PrashantValanda

Comment: Post new question with your code and full detail what the issue are you facing

Comment: To prevent Unknown column on where clause you need to add one more field `'filter_index'` in your addColumn method, like that `$this->addColumn('new_id', array(
            'header' => "New Id",
            'index' => 'new_id',
   'filter_index' => 'new_id',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '100px',
            'options' => $newIdOptions,
        ));`

Comment: $this->addColumn('warehouse ', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('warehouse'),
    'index' => 'warehouse',
 'type'  => 'text',
    'width' => '70px',
     'sortable'  => false,
            'filter'    => false,
    'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productatt',
));

Comment: above is my code, but filter option not applied,

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/196004/57334