# Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous when adding custom order attribute to grid and changing store

Tags: sales-order, order-grid, order-collection

I have created a custom order attribute and I am now able to show it in the sales order grid; my previous question: [Adding custom sales order attribute to order grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104336/adding-custom-sales-order-attribute-to-order-grid/104339?noredirect=1#comment141867_104339)

If I were to change the drop down of `Purchased From (Store)` and try to filter the grid by a specific store, I get redirect back to the dashboard view in backend and when I revisit the sales order grid, I start getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous

I believe the issue is with the way I join onto the `sales_flat_order` table:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft(array
    (
        'order' => Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
        'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
        array('sales_rep' => 'sales_rep')
    );
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

But I am not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

use below code just before the `$this->setCollection($collection);`

```
$collection->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
```

Second Solution edit your column code:

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
                'filter_index' => 'main_table.store_id',
            ));
        }
```

hope this helps you

Comment: After a few trial and errors, I understood the issue and eventually arrived at the same (#2) solution.

Comment: Adding **`->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id')`** worked for me. Thanks @prashant-valanda

Comment: works fine! not found any other solution

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you do the addColumn. By doing a join with `sales_flat_order` all columns will be ambiguous when you try to make the `addColumn`.

What you should do is in columns that can be ambiguous should put the prefix of the table. `main_table` for `sales_flat_order_grid` and in the case of the code must be sales_rep: `order`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it, the issue was NOT with the `_prepareCollection()` method - it was fine.

The problem was with the `_prepareColumns()` method, because both tables `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order` has a `store_id` and the `addColumn` method did not know which one to use.

So, I did this:

```
if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'main_table.store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    ));
}
```

And this has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, but at the end i got a solution, The complete solution for the issue:
First copy the core file in local directory:

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

To

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Now

**Step 1.** In your app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php file find the function _prepareColumns() , Inside this function find the below code

```
    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
    }
```

**Step 2.** replace the above code with below one

```
  if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
    $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
        'index'     => 'main_table.store_id',
        'type'      => 'store',
        'store_view'=> true,
        'display_deleted' => true,
    ));
  }
```

**Step 3.** Now again search below code in same function _prepareColumns()

```
   $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
   ));
```

**Step 4.** just replace the code with below one

```
   $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at',
        ));
```

**Step 5.** Now try to filter by G.T.(base) or G.T.(Purchased), if you still face issue for G.T.(base) and G.T.(Purchased) then replace the below code for both in the same function _prepareColumns()

```
    $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.base_grand_total',
        ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
            'filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
        ));
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

We should use
'filter_index' => 'main_table.grand_total',
line of code and smbigios error will dissapear.

Solution from Ajendra Panwar works for me. Thanks