# How to get custom customer attribute value in sales order grid?

Tags: sales-order, order-grid, customer-attribute

I have made customer attribute 'sales_executive' which shows proper value in customer grid.
Now i want to show the same value in sales order grid by adding column. How to add this column and get value in it?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Magento 1.9x version

Comment: is your issue cleared?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom module:

`app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
    </global>

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- To register the controller action -->
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_register>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>registerController</method>
                    </my_module_custom_register>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
            <!-- Called after creating a block -->
            <core_layout_block_create_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_before_block>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>blockCreateAfter</method>
                    </my_module_custom_before_block>
                </observers>
            </core_layout_block_create_after>
            <!-- Called before loading a non EAV collection -->
            <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_custom_before_core_load_collection>
                        <class>module/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeCoreCollectionLoad</method>
                    </factoryx_custom_before_core_load_collection>
                </observers>
            </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php`:

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function registerController(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
        switch ($action)
        {
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_index':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_grid':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_exportCsv':
            case 'adminhtml_sales_order_exportExcel':
                Mage::register('adminhtml_sales_order_grid', true);
                break;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function blockCreateAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        if($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        {
            $block->addColumnAfter(
                'accref',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Account Reference'),
                    'index' => 'accref',
                    'filter_index' => 'cust.value',
                ),
                'created_at'
            );
        }
    }

    public function beforeCoreCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

        if (Mage::registry('adminhtml_sales_order_grid')) {

            $collection = $observer->getCollection();
            if (!isset($collection)) {
                return;
            }

            if ($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection) {
                // Get the attribute id for the accref attribute
                $eavAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
                $accrefId = $eavAttribute->getIdByCode('customer', 'accref');
                $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                    array('cust' => Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('customer_entity_varchar')),
                    'main_table.customer_id = cust.entity_id AND cust.attribute_id = '.$accrefId,
                    array(
                        'cust.value'
                    )
                );
}
```

And obviously:

`app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**EDIT**

Using `_prepareCollection()` you can view this link

[Adding custom sales order attribute to order grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104336/adding-custom-sales-order-attribute-to-order-grid)

Comment: Don't want to create observer for it. If you can help me by function _prepareCollection() in grid.php in sales/order?

Comment: check my updated answer. or checkout this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104336/adding-custom-sales-order-attribute-to-order-grid.

Comment: @chirag I am using this module https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee, the extra fees field value applied but the field column not visible backend order total,  may i know whats is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You will achieve this with the help of renderer.
You just need to `addColum` in your order grid and pass the renderer class in that. and create that renderer class page wherever you want.

You can perform/load any value there and return whatever you want to show in grid.

You can get the help from [this example](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/).