# How to obtain customer attribute in sales order grid?

Tags: sales-order, order-grid, customer-attribute

I have made a customer attribute as 'sales_executive' and it is displayed in **add new customer** form in admin. It is also displayed in customer grid by adding a add column and but now I want to display the same column in sales order grid also. So What I want to ask is Do I need to make another 'sales' attribute for it. Or How to do it?

[image: Add New Customer Form. Added dropdown attribute as 'Sales Executive']

[image: Customer Grid where a column is added as 'Sales Executive' and Id is also displayed.]

[image: Sales Order Grid. I have added a column as same 'Sales Executive' but unable to get Collection of this customer attribute.]

How to obtain collection in Sales Order grid? Any logic change? Or what to write in _prepareCollection() ?

Comment: @Marius Can you please help me?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again and again? 

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149628/how-to-get-custom-customer-attribute-value-in-sales-order-grid

there is a facility to edit your question.

Comment: You want this value for logged in user only or also for guest user ?